# How can an angular controller can communicate with a sibling controller?

Tags: angularjs, scope, push

I have just seen a code that works but that I do not understand :
The aim is to add a movie in an array of movies called [movies].
We can find this array in a first controller ctrl1 :

```
angularMovieApp.controller("ctrl1" ,function ($scope) {
$scope.movies = [
    {id: 1,
        title : "Avatar",
        releaseYear : "2010",
        poster : "img/avatar.jpg",

    { id: 2,
        title : "Yip Man 2",
        releaseYear : "2010",
        poster : "img/yipman.jpg"
    }
];
```

Ctrl2 is a sibling of Ctrl1 (not a chil or a parent).  It add a new movie (movie)thanks to a form html and add it to the array [movies] with this line of code :

```
    angularMovieApp.controller("Ctrl2" ,function ($scope) {
    $scope.addMovie = function(movie){
    $scope.movies.push(movie);
    $scope.movie = {};
};
```

How does Ctrl2 understand what is [movies] and can complete it whereas it is not in is scope ?
Thank you for your explanation

Here the html code :

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="moviesController">

<header class="page-header">
    <h1>Ma vidéothèque <small>{{movies.length}} films</small>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#movie-form-modal">Ajouter un film</button>
    </h1>
</header>

<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li ng-repeat="movie in movies" class="span12">
        <img ng-src="{{movie.poster}}" class="span2">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{movie.title}}</h3>
            <p><b>Année de sortie : </b>{{movie.releaseYear}}</p>
            <p><b>Réalisateur : </b>{{movie.directors}}</p>
            <p><b>Acteurs : </b>{{movie.actors}}</p>
            <p><b>Synopsis : </b>{{movie.synopsis}}</p>
            <p><b>Note : </b>{{movie.rate}}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

?

#### Ajouter un film

Titre :
                
            
            
                Année de sortie :
                
            
            
                Réalisateur : 
                
            
            
                Acteurs :
                
            
            
                Synopsis :
                
            
            
                Note :
                
            
        
    
    
        Annuler
        Ajouter

Here is the complete js code :
angularMovieApp.controller("moviesController" ,function ($scope) {

```
$scope.movies = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title : "Avatar",
        releaseYear : "2010",
        poster : "img/avatar.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title : "Seigneur des Anneaux : La Communauté de l'Anneau",
        releaseYear : "2003",
        poster : "img/seigneurdesanneaux1.jpg",
        directors : "Peter Jackson"
    }
];
```

});

angularMovieApp.controller("movieFormController" ,function ($scope) {

```
$scope.addMovie = function(movie){
    $scope.movies.push(movie);
    $scope.movie = {};
};
```

});

I find this code here : https://github.com/lauterry/angularmovie.git
(step-3-solution)

Emmanuelle

Comment: This shouldn't be possible as you've described it. We would need to see the relevant code for both controllers and the HTML markup where they are used.

Comment: Probably because angular is passing a reference of the array object to the controller

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I have now added html and .js. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have understood.
there is an error in the code. The section with the first controller was not closed. If I close it, it appears clearly that Ctrl1 is the parent of Ctrl2. Ctrl 2 can therefore read Ctrl1.
Thank you. You help me to see it clearly.